# I'm getting "Access denied: DriveApp." but all permissions were allowed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I read all the other threads on this and haven't found a solution. I wrote some code that works fine in a number of accounts but there is one workspace account where the code fails and it says "Exception: Access denied: DriveApp. at" and it gives the line where the error happens, which is `docFile.moveTo(docFolder);` (both docFile and docFolder are defined - again, the exact same code works fine in other accounts).

I checked that DriveApp is activated in the Admin Console:
[image]

Can't figure out what else to try. I can share minimal reproducible example, but I'm pretty sure this isn't something in the code itself, it's something in the Workspace environment that isn't right and I don't know what. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure that the problematic account has access to the folder and the file?

Comment: Yes. The folder and the file are created earlier in the script in their own account. And it's worked for everyone else whop's used it. :-/